# How to grow hair in this style?

Tags: personal-care, hair

Recently I'm thinking about change my hairstyle. I run into some hairsyles that I like. One of them is this: 
[image]

How can I grow hair like this? I have medium straight hair now, and I want to know how I should cut it (or tell people to cut it) regularly until it looks like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep this picture on your phone. Each time you get a haircut, show the haircutter this picture first.  Tell them that this is the look that you (eventually) want. They will know how to cut your hair correctly at each step of the way, and they can probably advise you how long you should wait until your next haircut.